# zXing (ios version) Black/White screen error

Tags: objective-c, ios, avfoundation, zxing

I'm working over application, that using zxing library to read QRcodes. I have problem with `ZxingWidgetController` - when view is showed, during application is in background/not active (eg. screen is lock) image from camera is not shown on screen - only background is visible, and scanner seems to be not working.

when i call `initCapture` method again, after a little delay video from camera is showed, but in this case, every time when application lose activity i need to reinitialize scanner - this behavior is not comfortable at all.

this bug can be repeated on almost all aplication used zXing, so i suppose that is some zXing bug.

zXing initCapture method code is:

```
- (void)initCapture {
#if HAS_AVFF
  AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput =
    [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:
            [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] 
                                          error:nil];
    if(!captureInput)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - CaptureInputNotInitialized");
    }


  AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init]; 
  captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
    if(!captureOutput)
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - CaptureOutputNotInitialized");
    }


  [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

  NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
  NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];

  NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];

  [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings]; 
  self.captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
  self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium; // 480x360 on a 4

    if([self.captureSession canAddInput:captureInput])
    {
        [self.captureSession addInput:captureInput];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - cannot add input");
    }
    if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:captureOutput])
    {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ERROR - cannot add output");
    }

  [captureOutput release];

  if (!self.prevLayer)
  {
      [self.prevLayer release];
  }
  self.prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];

  // NSLog(@"prev %p %@", self.prevLayer, self.prevLayer);
  self.prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
  self.prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
  [self.view.layer addSublayer: self.prevLayer];

  [self.captureSession startRunning];
#endif
}
```

Maybe you guys know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I dont understand your question. If application is in background/not active, of course it cant working. You should make it clear.

Comment: You have right - I'm writing about situation, when application was in background while zxing initialization, and next was move to front.